# BSC Token Explorer

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, binance, binance-smart-chain

I'm looking for a solution to get all available and new BEP-20 tokens on the Binance Smart Chain. I tried it with web3py to analyze all transactions and extract the token from the input field but looks not the right way. I tried the BSCscan API, Pancakeswap API und Web3py but nobody provides that endpoint.

Here are my current solution to get all transactions:

```
from web3 import Web3
import time

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'))

def handle_event(event):
    try:
        transaction = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(event)
        print ('\n****************TRANSACTION****************')
        print (transaction)
        print ('*******************************************\n')
    except:
        pass

def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
        time.sleep(poll_interval)

def main():
    transactions = web3.eth.filter('pending')
    log_loop(transactions, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

with transaction.input and inside logs I would see the transferred token...

BTW: Anyone here who have a working solution to extract the token from input without slicing the string by hand?

Anyone knows a better way to get all BEP-20 token? My goal would be something similar like: https://poocoin.app/ape

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with the BitQuery API - you can use it free for X amount of requests: https://graphql.bitquery.io/ide/WQfM3F2ZSz

The link above is for all new Ethereum based tokens, but you can have a look in the shared queries, or write your own, to get the BSC tokens.